# JsonResponse Returns NOT serializable error in Django view

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to pass data to the template in Json format. JsonResponse returns an error

> **TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable**

Here is the code view that causes the error:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ... SOME CODE HERE ....
    elif request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        df = pd.read_csv(project.base_file,  encoding='ISO-8859-1')
        cols = df.keys
        return JsonResponse({'features': cols, }, status=200)
    else:
        form = mForm(project_id=pk)
```

The Json Data should be processed in the following Ajax Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var id_number =$("#projectID").text();
        
    $("#btnSelect").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                project_id: id_number,
            },
            success: function(response){
                $("#id_features").text(response.features)
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
df = pd.read_csv(project.base_file,  encoding='ISO-8859-1')
cols = df.keys
          ^
```

because `keys` is a method and you can't serialize a method into JSON(that's the error title right?) and since you want `df` value as serialized JSON, you must call that method to achieve it

but try

```
cols=df.keys()
```